# How to use Google App Engine's (Java) Task Queues to Persist a lot of data / rows in one Entity

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task-queue

I'm trying to persist roughly 28,000 "rows" in a single entity e.g. EMPLOYEE

Basically, my goal is to avoid being terminated / timing out by using PUTs that exceed 30 seconds - which is what might happen if I just do 28,000 PUTs by invoking a doPost() request sent to a servlet.

So I'm thinking of using tasks described in the Google App Engine documentation.

Essentially, I would like to upload a csv file in the war directory with 28,000 "employees". Then create a task that will async PUT these 28,000 employee rows to the EMPLOYEE entity.

- Q1: Is this a viable solution or is there a better way? Again, the goal is to performthe PUTs to avoid being terminated due to the 30 second limit.
- Q2: Also what queue.xml configurations should I use to ensure I can perform these PUTs as fast as possible?
- Q3: Now, I've tried it, similar to blog entry: http://gaejexperiments.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/episode-10-using-the-task-queue-service/ but I'm getting the following error after 23 or so seconds:

  ```
  SEVERE: Job default.task1 threw an unhandled Exception: 
  com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 5: http method POST against URL http://127.0.0.1:8888/dotaskservlet timed out.
      at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.dev.LocalURLFetchService.fetch(LocalURLFetchService.java:236)
      at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.dev.LocalTaskQueue$UrlFetchServiceLocalTaskQueueCallback.execute(LocalTaskQueue.java:471)
      at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.dev.UrlFetchJob.execute(UrlFetchJob.java:77)
      at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:203)
      at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
  16/02/2011 12:12:55 PM org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger schedulerError
  SEVERE: Job (default.task1 threw an exception.
  org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 5: http method POST against URL http://127.0.0.1:8888/dotaskservlet timed out.]
      at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:214)
      at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
  * Nested Exception (Underlying Cause) ---------------
  com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 5: http method POST against URL http://127.0.0.1:8888/dotaskservlet timed out.
      at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.dev.LocalURLFetchService.fetch(LocalURLFetchService.java:236)
      at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.dev.LocalTaskQueue$UrlFetchServiceLocalTaskQueueCallback.execute(LocalTaskQueue.java:471)
      at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.dev.UrlFetchJob.execute(UrlFetchJob.java:77)
      at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:203)
      at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
  ```
- Q4: I've also checked the Datastore Viewer at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin and it seems to have only created 1000 results in that entity. Is 1000 the limit?
- Q5: How do I get rid of that above error?
- Q6: Can any confirm that the maximum allowed time is 10minutes for a task? or is it still 30seconds? I did come accross this: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview.html#Task_Execution

Comment: Btw, I think your misinterpreting the concept of an Entity. Each 'entity' is an instance of a 'kind' (as object is to class in Java, as row is to table in a database). I assume you mean you want to create 28 000 entities of the kind EMPLOYEE? See for example http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities.html#Kinds_IDs_and_Names

Comment: Yes, your assumptions are correct. Sorry for the badly used/ mix terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is only to upload a bunch of data yourself, and not to allow your users to do so, I think an easier tool would be the bulk uploader.  You can just run a python program from your local machine that takes care of request limits and failure recovery for you.

http://ikaisays.com/2010/06/10/using-the-bulkloader-with-java-app-engine/

Comment: This blog entry looks more difficult to apply since I have been using GAE with Java. I've read through it but it still seems quite foreign. I've read http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/ and have a better understand of how GAE with pyhton works. So I'll give it ago after I try this first: http://ikaisays.com/2010/08/11/using-the-app-engine-mapper-for-bulk-data-import/

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example/tutorial of using mapreduce to parse a CSV-file, seems to be similar to your needs:

http://ikaisays.com/2010/08/11/using-the-app-engine-mapper-for-bulk-data-import/

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with batched save via `DeferredTask`, roughly something like this:

```
List<Employee> employees=...
EmployeeWriter qr = new EmployeeWriter (employees);
TaskHandle task = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue().add(withPayload(qr));
```

where

```
public class EmployeeWriter implements DeferredTask {
   public EmployeeWriter () {    }
   public EmployeeWriter (List<Employee> employees) { 
          this.employees=new LinkedList(employees);  
   }

    private LinkedList<Employee> employees;

    @Override
    public void run() {
      Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.createStarted();
      try {
        do {
           List employeesTosave=Pull100EmployeesFromLinkedList(employees)
           ofy().save(employeesTosave).now();

        } while (sw.elapsed(TimeUnit.MINUTES) < 9);
     finally {
        sw.stop();
        if (!employees.isEmpty()) {
            QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue().add(withPayload(this));
        }
    }

}
```